# javascript first dropdown option loads a new page url

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select

If you have a dropdown select, how can you make it so if a user clicks the first option it will load another page url.

For example

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<select name="myform" id="myform">
<option value="new-page.html">[New Customer]</option>
<option value="1">Jim Jones</option>
<option value="2">John Doe</option>
</select>
```

From this if you clicked the dropdown "New Customer" it would redirect the user to the page to create a new user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<option onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.exampl.org';
  " value="new-page.html">[New Customer]</option>
```